# ssh: add "-X" to default options

Tags: linux, ssh, alias

How do I add "-X" into my ssh default option? i.e., when I type ssh A.B.C.D, it should really do ssh -X A.B.C.D

I can alias it, but is there a more "elegant" solution to do that in .ssh/config file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the ~/.ssh/config file ForwardX11 or ForwardX11Trusted options.

Specifically, if you want to add -X to *every invocation* of ssh, put something like this in your config file:

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

If you want to use if only for certain hosts, you need to set up a host specification for each host:

```
Host <hostname>
  ForwardX11 yes
```

Check out the man page for ssh_config and ssh for more details.